# Clustering data using DBSCAN and spark_sklearn

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I want to cluster my input data using DBSCAN and spark_sklearn. I'd like to get the labels of each input instance after clustering. Is it possible?

Reading the documentation on http://pythonhosted.org/spark-sklearn, I tried the following:

```
temp_data = Spark DataFrame containing 'key' and 'features' columns, 
            where 'features' is a Vector.

ke = KeyedEstimator(sklearnEstimator=DBSCAN(), estimatorType="clusterer")
print ke.getOrDefault("estimatorType") --> "clusterer"

ke.fit_pedict(temp_data) --> ERROR: 'KeyedEstimator' object has no attribute 'fit_predict'

k_model = ke.fit(temp_data)
print k_model.getOrDefault("estimatorType") --> "clusterer"

k_model.fit_pedict(temp_data) --> ERROR: 'KeyedModel' object has no attribute 'fit_predict'

k_model.predict(temp_data) --> ERROR: 'KeyedModel' object has no attribute 'predict'

k_model.transform(temp_data) --> ERROR: estimatorType assumed to be a clusterer, but sklearnEstimator is missing fit_predict() 
(NOTE: sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN actually have fit_predict() method)
```

What I normally do using sklearn (without spark) is to fit (`dbscan_model.fit(temp_data-features)`) and get labels from the model (`labels = dbscan_model.labels_`). It is also fine if I can get the 'labels_' attribute using spark-sklearn.

If the above-mentioned calls ('transform' or 'predict') doesn't work, is it possible to get the 'labels_' after fitting data using spark-sklearn? How can I do that? Assuming that we obtained the 'labels_', how can I map the input instances to the labels_? Do they have same order?

Comment: Avoid using software that wraps around software that wraps around software ... stackinglayer onto layer kills performance (and pyspark already has the reputation of being slow), and you don't get all the functionality anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's just possible in the case of `KMeans`, in which we can predict cluster labels, since the scikit-learn estimator provides this functionality.

Unfortunately, this is not the case for some other clusterers, such as DBSCAN.

Comment: For DBSCAN, is there a way for getting the clusters of input instances? sckit-learn allows to reach 'labels_' attribute.

Comment: @user2737636 Yes, DBSCAN has a labels_ attribute just the same as KMeans

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the 'labels_' attribute; however I still don't know if the order of resulting labels are same as the input instances or not.

```
temp_data = Spark DataFrame containing 'key' and 'features' columns, 
        where 'features' is a Vector.

ke = KeyedEstimator(sklearnEstimator=DBSCAN())
k_model = ke.fit(temp_data)

def getLabels(model):
    return model.estimator.labels_

labels_udf = udf(lambda x: getLabels(x).tolist(), ArrayType(IntegerType()))("estimator").alias("labels")
res_df = km_dbscan.keyedModels.select("key", labels_udf)
```